# Replace part of Worksheet by Exporting Python Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, excel, export-to-excel, dataframe

I have an established Excel worksheet and now I want to update some sheets by directly using results from Python. Say the area is `B2:D12 in sheet "hey" in eg.xlsx`, I already had the required data as of a pandas data frame (say, A). Now I want to replace values in `B2:D12` with `A` in Python and keep the original formats.

I was writing something like this:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('eg.xlsx') as writer:
    A.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = 'hey',index = False,startcol = 1,startrow = 1)
```

However no matter how big the workbook was, the result is just 1 plain workbook with only 1 worksheet named "hey" and a default format in Python.

Anyone knows how to keep everything else same, but just replace that specific area with the data frame I have?

Thanks very much in advance!

PS. I also tried xlrd and xlwt (tho not sophisticated at all), however 1) I don't know how to write the whole data frame, starting with one cell only (like B2), 2) How to keep the original format in Excel? 3) I can't refer  to the sheet name but the sheet sequence only.

```
import xlrd,xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy
rb = xlrd.open_workbook('eg.xlsx')
wb = copy(rb)
ws = wb.get_sheet(3) # I can't refer to the sheet with sheet name!

ws.write(0,0,'hello')
ws.write(1,1,'world',plain)
wb.save('output.xls')
```